# Parse/Deserialize QueryString with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, query-string

I am new to `Objective-C` development type and I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to `deserialize` a `Query String` of that follow this schema:

```
"property1=valueA:0;valueB:5;valueC:10;&property2=valueD"
```

The `property1` can be empty which will then produce the following `Query String`.

```
"property1=null:0;&property2=valueA"
```

I know for other programing languages like `C#` we have some libraries to `deserialize` `JSON`, `Query Strings`, etc. But is there something that I can use for `Objective-C`? Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: Is your question something for which you cannot get the answer with a simple search?  If so, tell us why your question is so unique.

Comment: I have been trying to find for existing libraries for parsing query string values in Objective-C but couldn't find anything. I am wondering whether some standard library is available. That's all.

Comment: NSURLComponents